# How to stop receiving repeated OnKeyPress events on a TForm?

Tags: forms, delphi, delphi-2009

I have a main Form and when I select an item and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> a second modal Form is shown. This has some `TEdit` controls to change the item parameters. When the user has finished, he can press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to cancel or <kbd>Enter</kbd> to update the item, and close the edit Form.

The problem is that if the user presses and holds <kbd>Enter</kbd>, a loop is occurs. The Form is closed and opened again and then closed... and so on.

I changed the `WndProc` of the modal Form and cancel if the previous key state was pressed. But this works only if I don't have any controls on the Form. If I drop a `TEdit` (which is needed), the Form re-enters the loop. The modal Form has `KeyPreview` set to true, because I want to be able to validate the data from anywhere.

This is the minimal code to reproduce the problem:

After you test this, you can drop a `TEdit` on `Form2` and you will notice that a loop occurs.

**Form1:**

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses Unit2;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
 if Key = #13 then Form2.ShowModal;
end;

end.
```

**Form2:**

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
  protected
    procedure WndProc(var Msg: TMessage); override;
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 KeyPreview:= True;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
 if Key = #13 then begin Key:= #0; ModalResult:= mrOK; end;
end;

procedure TForm2.WndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
 if (Msg.Msg = WM_CHAR) and ((Msg.LParam and $40000000) <> 0) then Exit;
 inherited;
end;

end.
```

Comment: How about unselecting the `item` in the main form, on return from the modal form?

Comment: If it's only valid to press ENTER if Edit1 has a value, why not check that also: if (key = #13) then if (trim(Edit1.Text) <> '') then begin Key := #0; ModalResult := mrOK; end else Key := #0;

Comment: @TomBrunberg the item must remain selected.

Comment: @ALombardo, I check it, but if it's valid the loop will occur.

Comment: But it won't be an endless loop, since the only way out of form2 is either escape or edit Edit1.text and hit enter.  I guess you'll have to clear Edit1.text as you exit, you can get that value before it closes and implement what ever it is that needs to be done.

Comment: Default valid values are loaded on form show and the user cand press Enter immediately. This will generate an endless loop. :(

Comment: It's hard to figure a solution since you don't really show what the code does when ModalResult = mrOK in Form1

Comment: Why would the item have to stay selected, surely you can use a separate variable, to remeber/indicate what was selected. The point is that you must break the loop, isn't it?

Comment: Or you can use `OnKeyDown` / `OnKeyUp` instead of `OnKeyPress`. Those one's won't repeat when held down.

Comment: I tried. It is repeated too.

Comment: -*"problem is that if the user presses and holds Enter, a loop is occurs"* - There cannot be any solution for that problem. I would suggest you to ask the user why he/she is holding the Enter key. Who knows, they might become discouraged doing it.

Comment: The best way should be using the KeyUp event in both forms as the KeyUp is just fired when the user releases the key. This should fix your loop problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's impossible to hook `TWinControl.DoKeyPress` to solve this issue as it should, I came up with this workaround:

**Form1:**

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Application.OnActivate:= AppActivate;
end;

procedure TForm1.AppActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 EnterReleased:= (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) and $8000) = 0;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
 if Key = #13 then begin
  Key:= #0;
  if EnterReleased then begin
   EnterReleased:= False;
   Form2.ShowModal;
  end;
 end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
 if Key = VK_RETURN then EnterReleased:= True;
end;
```

**Form2:**

```
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 KeyPreview:= True;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
 if Key = #13 then begin
  Key:= #0;
  if EnterReleased then begin
   EnterReleased:= False;
   ModalResult:= mrOK;
  end;
 end;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
 if Key = VK_RETURN then EnterReleased:= True;
end;
```